# Android File.setReadyOnly() not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to set a files permissions as read only but it appears to be having no effect. Here is the code:

```
File file = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "testFile");

if (!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}

boolean successful = file.setReadOnly();
boolean canRead = file.canRead();
boolean canWrite = file.canWrite();

Log.d("TAG", String.format("Permissions write successful: %s for file: %s", successful, file.getAbsolutePath()));
Log.d("TAG", String.format("Can read: %s , Can write: %s", canRead, canWrite));
```

When performing the above the console output is:

```
D/TAG: Permissions write successful: true for file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package.name/files/testFile
D/TAG: Can read: true , Can write: true
```

I should not be able to write to that file though. What is the problem here?

Comment: you can also write on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, since I am not totally confirmed, you can't change the read only if the file is placed on external storage.
Since I am not sure with the exact documentation but I have had the same issue, you may fine these lines from docs helpful.

Here is documentation:

**External storage:**
 **- It's world-readable, so files saved here may be read outside of your control. When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes your
app's files from here only if you save them in the directory from
getExternalFilesDir().**

You may follow full summary [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Comment: This does seem to be the case but i can't find any documentation saying so, have you seen any?